# how to Use values from a specific line from within the textarea to submit GET form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to use values from a specific line from within the TextArea to submit a form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type='button' value='submit' onclick='document.getElementById("submit-line-3") .submit();'/>

<textarea>
aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd
eee-fff-ggg-hhh
iii-jjj-kkk-lll
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

For example:
I want to send a form GET to search.php so that the GET values are extracted from within TextArea.

So the JavaScript reads the example of the third line and sends it to a https://example.com/search.php file, and the form is sent like this:
https://example.com/search.php?val1=iii&val2=jjj&val3=kkk&cel=lll

And to send a request GET, silently hidden without reloading the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that picks out line 2 from your text area and adds it as a URL parameter (note: make sure to encode anything you're sending in a get request).

```js
function submit() {
  const textarea = document.getElementById("my-textarea");
  const sections = textarea.value
    .split("\n")[2]
    .split("-")
    .map((el, i) => {
    return `val${i+1}=${el}`;
  }).join("&")
  
  // Now do a fetch request
  const url = 'your-url?' + encodeURI(sections);
  console.log(url);
  // your-url?val1=iii&val2=jjj&val3=kkk&val4=lll
  fetch(url);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my-textarea">
aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd
eee-fff-ggg-hhh
iii-jjj-kkk-lll</textarea>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: GET Result = ?textValue=eee-fff-ggg-hhh

I want to divide the line values into 4 values like:

?val1=eee&val2=fff&val3=ggg&val4=hhh

Comment: Updated to accommodate this slightly unique use case!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :)

Javascript:

```
var lines = document.getElementById('submit-line-3').innerHTML.split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //AJAX code here using lines[i] which will send each line
}
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //AJAX code here using lines[i] which will send each line
}
```

Working example here:

https://codepen.io/jknkjandjkna/pen/xxxyRad